# Can't read params from route URL

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I was trying create a simple component with my angular-cli project, which load parameter from URL

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './confirm-registration.component.html',
})
export class ConfirmRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => {
      return console.log('token:', params['registrationToken']);
    });
  }

}
```

but I got error:

Failed to compile.

> .../confirm-registration.component.ts (15,33): Argument of type
>   '(params: Params) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '(value: Params, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.   Type 'void'
>   is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

I use Angular in 4.0.3 version. where I did make mistake?

Comment: can you try this console.log( this.route.snapshot.params['registrationToken'])

Comment: what is your route, may be it in req.query

Comment: You're using switchMap, which should return an Observable but you return result of calling `console.log`(in this case: void). Please use `do` operator to log to console for debugging purposes:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fetch the query parameter with this:

```
export class ConfirmRegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

private registrationToken: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(
  (params) => {
    this.registrationToken = params['registrationToken'];
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As *dzejdzej* has pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197937/cant-read-params-from-route-url/44348192#comment75409457_44197937), you have to return an observable. This seems to have changed in the last months (at least it compiled the last time I tried some months ago), and they have not changed the docs yet.

So in your case you could simply return the same observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => {
    console.log('token:', params['registrationToken']);
    return this.route.params;
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but now I got error: 

Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'.

Comment: You have to import the operator from rxjs

Answer (score 0):

To get query parameters, I did this with angular-2. I'm not sure if it works with angular-4

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

}

ngOnInit() {
  let urParam = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['urParam'];
}
```

Hope this helps